# ActiveMQ integration with Istio

Tags: activemq-classic, istio

We are using ActiveMQ 5.15.6. We have deployed it as a container on a Kubernetes cluster. We have exposed the ActiveMQ web console using a load balancer.

Now we are setting up a service mesh using Istio, for which we have to enable a strict TLS on all the namespaces (applications). After enabling the TLS we are unable to use the load balancer. So to expose the web-console we need to create a virtual service and a gateway which will do the routing.

We have created the virtual service and tried to expose it on path `/activemq` but it is not working as expected. Also we changed the routing path `/admin` to `/activemq` in `jetty.xml` as `/admin` was conflicting with our other application path.

Kindly help us to understand how can we set the proper routing using a virtual service.

Note: We also tried it with nginx-ingress and it didn’t work.

Virtual Service :

```
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: activemq-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - default/backend-gateway
  http:
  - name: activemq-service
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /activemq
    rewrite:
      uri: /activemq
    route:
    - destination:
        host: active-mq.activemq.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8161
```

Comment: Please include your manifest as actual text, not an image. It will make replicating your issue easier.

Comment: Added virtaulservice.yaml file

Comment: What response or error do you get ? Could you include your gateway yaml file ?